# Are threads part of standard C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Is there thread handling in new C++ standard? And if i will write multithreaded apps does it mean application will use more cores of cpu? ( if available )

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread

Comment: Why ask something that you can easily find out for yourself, e.g. on Wikipedia's C++11 page or any decent C++ reference site?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is there thread handling in new C++ standard?

Yes, as of **C++11** there is [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), `std::async` and others.

> And if i will write multithreaded apps does it mean application will use more cores of cpu? ( if available )

Only if you use them right.

Comment: @fex Write code that 1) creates the appropriate number of threads 2) which operate independently and do not block each other [much] 3) while still implementing the task correctly without race conditions ;-)

Comment: thanks, one more question :P can i "forget" about all these platform specifed threads functions (like WinApi threads) and rely only on threads implemented by c++ standard :P?

Comment: @fex: You sure can, but you could have done it years ago. **Boost.Thread** has been around for years, and is what the standard threads are based on.